# Display multiple markers on google map by providing address

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have the following script to use the google maps API, I have to create a map that has more than one Marker (the balloon shaped icon pointing to something) and i need each of those markers to point on a different area of the map (i.e. different coordinates), how can i do it?
NOTE: I do not have latitude and longitude for the area on which marker has to be placed instead I have the address of the area on which marker has to be placed.

The code to display multiple markers on Google map is given below but it does not work as expected!

```
var map = null;
var geocoder = null;

function initializeNew() {
    var allAddress = document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value;
    var testary = new Array();
    testary = allAddress.split("|");

       if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
       //calls map to appear inside <div> with id, "map_canvas"
       map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

       //adds zoom and arrow controls to map
       //map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());

       var marker = null;
       var i = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < testary.length; i++) {

           address = testary[i];

           geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();


           //converts a street address into geocode for the api 
           geocoder.getLatLng(
          address,
          function(point) {
              if (!point) {
                  alert(address + " not found");
              } else {
                  map.setCenter(point, 13);
                  marker = new GMarker(point);
                  map.addOverlay(marker);

                  map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);

                  //adds your own marker title and description in html
                  marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<p class='para1bold' style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Address</p><p class='para1'>" + address + "</p>");
                  //Add click event on push pin to open info window on click of the icon
                  GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                  marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<p class='para1bold' style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Address</p><p class='para1'>" + address + "</p>");
              });
                  //Provides map,satellite,hybrid and terrain views in the map along with zoom control
                  map.setUIToDefault();
              }
          }
    )
      }


  }  
}
```

I have stored address of group of items in an array and looped to display markers in the map. This displays only one marker for the last address present in the array. Please correct this code or provide new code to display multiple markers in Google map by providing address.

Comment: have you tried to print out the result from Geocoding? all different lat & lng?

Comment: When I print the address variable (item in array) in the geocoder.getLatLng method's else part, it displays last item in the array(last address). I think it is displaying multiple markers in same position in Google map!! Anybody can guide me to correct the code!

Comment: Maybe the addresses you are providing to  google geocoder webervice are too similar, which may be causing same lat long result.

Answer (score 0):

try this: put `var` in front of marker

```
else {
              map.setCenter(point, 13);
              var marker = new GMarker(point);
              map.addOverlay(marker);

              map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);

              //adds your own marker title and description in html
              marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<p class='para1bold' style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Address</p><p class='para1'>" + address + "</p>");
              //Add click event on push pin to open info window on click of the icon
              GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
              marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<p class='para1bold' style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Address</p><p class='para1'>" + address + "</p>");
          });
```

***UPDATE***

```
var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

var addresses = ["new york","chicago"];
var curIndex = 0;

function showAddress() {
  var _cur = addresses[curIndex];
  geocoder.getLatLng(
    _cur,
    function(point) {
      if (!point) {
        alert(_cur + " not found");
      } else {
        console.log(_cur+":"+point);
      }
      //do next after done
      curIndex++;
      if(curIndex<addresses.length)
        showAddress();
    }
  );
}

showAddress();
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried to print out the result from Geocoding? all different lat & lng?

Comment: All the latitude and longitude of the addresses in the array are getting printed correctly... I think there is some issue in creating markers!

Comment: When I print the address variable (item in array) in the geocoder.getLatLng method's else part, it displays last item in the array(last address). I think it is displaying multiple markers in same position in Google map!! Anybody can guide me to correct the code!

Comment: cause geocoder.getLatLng is request/response function, like xmlHttprequest. you need to wait for the request finish then send another one. i will update  my answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same problem and [fixed it](http://justanothertriager.wordpress.com/2010/09/05/working-with-google-maps/).  Look at the code that I have used.  The specific bits are that marker needs to be an array and when you open the infowindow the content needs to be stored in the marker array.  I would also suggest that you use something JSON instead which is easier to parse instead of separating with '|'.